# Import medium sized CSV to JawsDB MySQL database

Tags: mysql, csv, heroku

I currently have a shared leopard Mysql DB attached to my heroku instance. The provider is JawsDB. I need to import a medium sized CSV, around 160,000 records. I am currently using the mysql workbench and have tried a few ways to import this without luck. I first tried using the import wizard, I quickly hit my max_questions resource and was unable to run any queries for a bit. I tried to use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE but do not have admin permissions to actually load this file. I can't find any other good answers online, any advice?

I do not have access to the remote machine/server, a connection through SQL clients.

Comment: *I need to import a medium sized CSV, around 160,000 records.* What is this file size in bytes. Does this value exceeds the maximal packet size setting value? If not then you may load the whole file into the query with LOAD_FILE() or even insert it into the query as string literal. Then you'd parse it to separate rows and columns then insert parsed data into your table. For MySQL 8+ you may use CTE, for 5.x you need in stored procedure. From the other side you may convert your CSV to a set of INSERT INTO queries (any text editor which can perform Replace by a pattern may do) and execute them.

Comment: The file isn't very large. Only around 8.2mb, I don't have access to the server itself only connection through programs like Heidi or Workbench. I've been getting access or permission errors when using other load file variations but I'll give your other options a try, thanks!

Comment: *Only around 8.2mb* Compare this with `SELECT @@max_allowed_packet;` output.

Comment: The MySQL Workbench Import Wizard writes single row inserts (using a prepared statement), which means each row counts as a question. To reduce the number of "questions used" you can use multi-row inserts. You could do this in your programming language of choice, or import the data to a local MySQL instance using `LOAD DATA INFILE` and then use mysqldump to create a SQL dump containing  multi-row inserts (is part of default `--opt` option).

Answer (score 0):

Create a Csv file in local machine

```
pip install pandas
```

Python script [import_csv_to_mysql.py] -

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

# Replace with your database connection details
database_url = "mysql://user_name:password@host_name:PORT/database_name"

# Read the CSV file
csv_path = "path/to/your/csv/file.csv"

db = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

# Create a database engine
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(database_url)

# Insert the data into the database
db.to_sql("table-name", engine, if_exists="replace", index=False)
engine.dispose()
```

run python script -

```
python import_csv_to_mysql.py
```